# Running callback on the same thread as the caller in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsthread, kotlin-native, runloop

I call a method on the native iOS side from Kotlin/Native framework. The method does its work asynchronously and responds back with some data in a different thread than it was called with.

I want a way to call the response function also in the same thread. Below is the code:

```
func makePostRestRequest(url: String, body: String) { 

    let thread1 = Thread.current

    let request = NetworkServiceRequest(url: url,
                                        httpMethod: "POST",
                                        bodyJSON: body)
    NetworkService.processRequest(requestModel: request) { [weak self] (response: Any?, requestStatus: RequestStatus) in
        // This is different thread than "thread1". Need the below code to execute on "thread1"
        if requestStatus.result == .fail {
            knResponseCallback.onError(errorResponse: requestStatus.error)
        } else {
            knResponseCallback.onSuccess(response: response)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to solve this using two ways.

One is to use "semaphores". I just blocked the code execution after the network call and when I got the result back in the callback of network request, I saved it in a variable and signal the semaphore. After that I just call knResponseCallback and use the response variable to return back the response.

Another way I used is to use RunLoops. I got the handle of RunLoop.current, start the runLoop in a mode and in the callback of network request, I just call `perform selector on thread with object` method of NSObject which dispatches the work to that thread itself.

*The problem with both of them is that they are blocking calls. RunLoop.run and semaphore.wait both blocks the thread they are called in.*

**Is there a way to dispatch some work onto a particular thread from another thread without blocking the particular thread?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a queue to send the request and use that same queue to handle the response. Something like this should work for you:

```
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my-thread")
        queue.async {
            let request = NetworkServiceRequest(url: url,
                                                httpMethod: "POST",
                                                bodyJSON: body)
            NetworkService.processRequest(requestModel: request) { [weak self] (response: Any?, requestStatus: RequestStatus) in
                queue.async {
                    if requestStatus.result == .fail {
                        knResponseCallback.onError(errorResponse: requestStatus.error)
                    } else {
                        knResponseCallback.onSuccess(response: response)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```